# osmbonouspack : maneuverType for GoogleRoadManager RoadNodes?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, routes, osmdroid

I'm getting my routing from GoogleRoadManager but all maneuverTypes from RoadNodes are 0 so I can't set an appropriate icon for it. can anyone help with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps Directions API do not provide maneuver types, only textual instructions. So, no way.

BTW, keep in mind that displaying a route provided by Google on a non-Google map (like OSM map) is not allowed by Google T&C.

But you can easily switch to another road manager.